# Is post payments possible through In-App purchase in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, in-app-purchase, xcode7

I am working on a cab application and have a requirement like need to charge 1$ from customers after completing the drop off. Is it possible to debit amount through In-App purchase? Are Pre payment and post payments possible through In-App purchase?

Answer (score 1):

We cannot debit amount with out user acceptance. 
We can only provide pay option to the user and user has to complete payment process by using his iTunes account credentials.
If its a cab service - its not a good idea to do with InApp purchase, as they will take 30% of your revenue.

By maintaining own wallet for App (as "Ola Money" by Ola cabs), you can have effective control of payment process. But it needs a development effort to build own wallet from scratch.

Comment: thank you for your reply. Is there any payment system which I get directly from Apple for each ride or trip?

Comment: Is there any payment system or way in which I can get every month $2  from customers through Apple for the application usage?